# Can not include header file

Tags: c++, include, eclipse-cdt

Hello now i try translate project on other platform(first platform it's windows, now company planed use Linux platform), i use eclipse in windows and Linux, language is c++. Name project PostLib and he have next structure: PostLib/common, PostLib/inc, PostLib/inc_ext, PostLib/src.

PostLib/common its part for control memory leaks and for smart pointer. PostLib/inc PostLib/inc_ext - this part for header, and PostLib/src for sources code.My problem next: In project settings, i use PostLib/common, PostLib/inc and PostLib/inc_ext, and Eclipse write error: File Def.h(PostLib/inc_ext) can not find file p_mem.h(PostLib/common). How can it be?

When i look property all direction in project i saw interesting thing: Property on directory PostLib/inc_ext difference than all project, on other directory property same like in project/ Property i mean Property->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Directories, i try add path (PostLib/common) , but no effect, Eclipse write error File Def.h(PostLib/inc_ext) can not find file p_mem.h(PostLib/common).

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems directory separator is `/`, not `\`!

`PostLib\common\p_mem.h` is a path in windows, but is not in Linux. The equivalent for Linux is `PostLib/common/p_mem.h`.

Also, filesystem paths on Linux are case sensitive. `p_mem.h` is a different file from `P_Mem.h`: be sure you used the right characters for files and directories.

Comment: Thanks, for check my grammatic mistake(/ \\), in project i use /, but in topic i write \. For case sensitive i know it is correct write